# Figuring out the name of a special goal

Tags: rocket-league

I'm playing Rocket League v1.0.3 on PC, in Unfair mode 1v2. There's been this special type of goal I have seldom encountered (I'm talking about goals like "Aerial goal", "Pool shot", etc.), and I'm trying to discover its name.

I tried to get a screenshot but for some reason PrtScn doesn't work with Rocket League on my PC (it copies a blank window), so I will try to describe it to you:

The icon* of this goal included a square and a circle (like on a PS4 controller), and perhaps another shape which I can't remember.
Also, the goal was scored by an AI (I played a lot of 1v2/1v1, and I've never managed to score this type of goal).

<sub>*shown at the top-right part of screen next to the scorer's name.</sub>

Does anyone recognize the goal I'm talking about? Thank you.

Comment: The Pool Shot goal is when you bump another player into the ball to score like a cue ball in pool (billiards), not sure about aerial goal or any others though.

Comment: If you're playing on Steam, you can hit F12 to take a screenshot

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT:** Without a proper picture, it will be very difficult to guess which award you are talking about. In any case, you can view all of these awards *in game* from the main menu under **Extras -> Stats**. Scroll through all of them until you find the symbol you are talking about.

The only thing that comes to mind is this symbol (top right, bottom of the stack):
[image: Playmaker Screenshot]

If so, that is the Playmakers Award, which is earned for every 3 assists in a single game.

Comment: If it's not this then I don't know what it would be.

Answer (score 1):

Backwards goal, looks like a gearshift.